# How to get Video Id from Youtub video Iframe in android

Tags: android, iframe, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have a iframe code in JSON array and i want to implement Youtube Api in my activity for this i need video id (Key) from below i frame. How can i get this programmatically in android.?

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/v_vmcXvMidM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I need this id "**v_vmcXvMidM**"

Comment: Well you don't need the API for that...

Comment: @johnh10 then how can i use this i frame..? i dont want to use webview or Intent